# Objective-C object-leak error

Tags: objective-c, ios5

For the program below i get the following error-
Potential leak of an object allocated on line 50.
Line 50 points to this line--
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
I tried to release receiveData after this statement but that gives me an error "object sent autorelease too many times." I am not sure if i am doing it the right way.Please help!

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

        NSURLRequest *theRequest = 
        [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://{your ip}:8080/activiti-rest/service/process-definitions?start=0&size=10&sort=id&order=asc"]                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                     timeoutInterval:10.0];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

        if (theConnection) {       

            self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

        } else {


            UIAlertView *connectFailMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NSURLConnection " message:@"Failed in viewDidLoad"  delegate: self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [connectFailMessage show];
            [connectFailMessage release];

        }

        [theConnection autorelease];

    }
```

**Edit** : In the header file it is declared as `@property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData;` 
**New**
It works after i removed this line[theConnection autorelease]. I kept the assign property as is in the header file and added the [self.receiveData release] like you asked.It did not work earlier because i kept this line [theConnection autorelease].I added it because i was wondering if i have to release theConnection object also.Can you please explain why that doesn't have to released?It is not released anywhere in the code and it still works??

Comment: How is receivedData declared in your header file?

Comment: I have edited it in my question.Kindly check that

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Need more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, the analyzer may potentially be confused.

Where is your balancing -release?  In -dealloc?

Why is this property *not* `retain` in the first place?

---

You should be releasing the object in -dealloc, too.   And you still haven't answered why the object is not `retain` -- that seems distinctly odd.

Comment: I am releasing the object in didFailWithError and didFinishLoading methods

Comment: I am starter and i am using http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/8/8b/URL_Connection_example.txt this link to start with.In this he has strictly mentioned to do the same in the .h file

Comment: The error was because i did not release the receivedData before assigning something to it.Also i guess i wrongly tried to release the theConnection object .I removed that line of code and it works now.Thanks!

Comment: Quick read indicates that said code is pretty poorly written.  At least, the management of `receivedData` appears to be nonsense.

Comment: I just realized that i got the application working by removing the [theConenction autorelease] line but the leak is still there.Can you please refer a good link for iOS app development

Comment: The analyzer is not confused. It is a memory leak if receivedData contains a retained object at the time of the assignment because the receivedData property does not have the retain attribute. It is also a memory leak if not released in dealloc.

Comment: The analyzer is confused;  it can't track releases that occur during normal API flow that do not happen in `dealloc`.  Rightly confused, at that, in that I agree that managing `receivedData` as a normal `retain` property that is `release`d in `dealloc` would be a far less confusing pattern.  Note that `assign` properties often have `retain`s maintained internally to the class, but outside of the normal pattern of `retain`d properties.

Answer (score 1):

self.receivedData is pointing to a property. Most likely this property has "retain" flag set. Therefore, it is retaining for you and your explicit retain in the line is extraneous and causing the issue.

Comment: If the property is `nonatomic,assign`, this answer can't be right.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `receivedData` property declared as `retain` in the corresponding header file?  This means that when you assign an object to it, that object is automatically sent a `retain` message.  You don't need to call `retain` on it yourself.

Comment: the property is declared as @property(nonatomic,assign) NSMutableData *receivedData;

Comment: It's not the usual approach to declare properties that are object types to be `assign` unless they are delegates or similar.  Try switching the property to `copy` or `retain` instead and remove the call to `retain`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are assigning receivedData without releasing it first. Try:

```
[self.receivedData release];
self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

Edit: Reason for the above.
receivedData is declared as an "assign" property. Therefore, if you assign to it without releasing it first, you have a memory leak if receivedData previously contained a retained object. You could of course change the property from assign to retain, but how do I know he doesn't have a good reason for using assign in the first place?

Comment: I tried this-
[self.receivedData release];
self.receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
It says incorrect decrement of reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller

Comment: It works after i removed this line[theConnection autorelease].

I kept the assign property as is in the header file and added the [self.receiveData release] like you asked.It did not work earlier because i kept this line [theConnection autorelease].I added it because i was wondering if i have to release theConnection object also.Can you please explain why that doesn't have to released?It is not released anywhere in the code and it still works??